# Spring Security: Multiple Logins to the same resources: Form Login + Facebook Connect (uid, sessionKey)

Tags: authentication, facebook, spring-security

To begin I know about

http://blog.kadirpekel.com/2009/11/09/facebook-connect-integration-with-spring-security/

The only problem is that it completely replaces the Form Login with Facebook Connect.

I have the native form login in place,

I also have Facebook Connect in place, Upon gathering user information I link it to a native account but without a password.

At that point I would like to call a link or method to start process of going into the
Spring Security Filter Chain.

---

Here is the [source code that works](http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-facebook/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/facebook/), but am trying to modify.
It contains all the files I'm taking about.

Now from what I understand I need to add a custom FacebookAuthenticationProvider so that my
AuthenticationManager knows about it.

```
<bean id="facebookAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider">
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="facebookAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Then within the FacebookAuthenticationProvider I would have to call an FacebookAuthenticationToken that would take my the current facebook Uid and SessionKey of the user.

Then try authenticate this Token.

So where does the FacebookAuthenticationFilter come into it?

I'm just trying to understand the order at which these 3 files are called.
As if you were trying to implement any other custom authentication.

```
FacebookAuthenticationFilter.java   
FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java     
FacebookAuthenticationToken.java
```

I have also posted this on the [Spring Security Forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=272098#post272098)

Answer (score 3):

I've written an article about multiple authentication providers with spring security (so e.g. one form login, one facebook login and one login with open-id). Hope that helps: http://thoean.com/programming/java/multiple-authentication-provider-with-spring-security/

Comment: Thank you markus.  I've tried it and it works fine.  The only problem I've found so far is that calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() always returns null, instead of the Facebook user id.

That is because FacebookAuthenticationToken#getPrincipal always returns null.  I've tried to write a wrapper that returns the proper user id with no success.  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Did you make sure that getPrincipal() of your token returns a value? I mean, which FacebookAuthenticationToken are you using?
I'm using my own - as an example you could set the first_name and last_name of the facebook user... or whatever.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is useful for you... I am using aop to secure my service methods and `ldapAuthenticationProvider`, however behavior was same with `dbAuthenticationProvider` too. I observed that calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` before invoking a secure method always return null but once a secure method is invoked it gets populated properly. This was with Spring security 3.0.5.RELEASE.